# query join 3 tables on laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have been working on this case for 3 days... Someone might give me a solution for the query report that I would like to create below.

I have 3 tables:

```
applicants
-id
-user_id
-name
-province_id

applications
-id
-user_id
-university_id

provinces
-id
-province_name
```

The goal of my query is providing total applicants for each province for on universities. Here is the table for this query

[image: list universities table]

Here's my query on MySQL:

```
select provinces.province_name, count(applicants.id) from provinces  left join applicants on provinces.id = applicants.province_id  join applications on applications.user_id = applicants.user_id--  where applications.university_id = 1 group by provinces.id;
```

this is my eloquent:

```
$output = DB::table('provinces')
    ->select(['provinces.province_name', DB::raw('count(applicants.id) as total'), 'provinces.id'])
    ->leftJoin('applicants', 'provinces.id','=', 'applicants.province_id' )
    ->leftJoin('applications', 'applications.user_id','=','applicants.user_id')
    ->where('university_id',$id)
    ->groupBy('provinces.id')
    ->get();
```

this is the sample current query:

[image]

this is my expectation:

[image]

Please provides the answer either in MySQL or eloquent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the '->leftJoin()' method? Seems to be perfectly capable of doing what you want from the looks of it :)

http://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#joins

Comment: I used to use the same approach. but when I add where based on the university_id, the data didn't show if the province doesn't have a university, instead, they only listing the province only if the count > 0.

Comment: Yes, true, because then your first select returns NULL if there are no universities for that province. The way it is now will only work if some data is found. If you turn that NULL into a 0 it should work :)

Comment: could you elaborate more your statement "turn that NULL into a 0?

Comment: If a query has no matching rows you get a NULL value instead of an array with the rows. Since a NULL can't be counted it won't work. If you incorporate an IF statement in the Raw query that's basically 'IF x == NULL, return 0' it should be a valid query.